# Is it legal to use two rackets in Table Tennis?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, racket

I've looked on Google, the official rules for Table Tennis, and on this website
but found nothing telling me whether it's illegal to use two rackets to play
table tennis. I understand there are rules which states there must be a "free hand" during the serve, but during ongoing play it is legal to use two hands to use a single racket or switch hands with the racket during an ongoing point.

Lastly in the rules they always say racket rather than racket(s), but it would seem somewhat unnecessary if they had said racket(s) seeing as no one actually uses more than one racket and it's too niche.

Answer (score 3):

*Rules of TT*:

> 2.5.2 The ball is in play  from the last moment at which it is  stationary on the palm of the free hand before being intentionally 
>   projected in service until the rally is decided as a let or a point. 
>   2.5.5 The racket hand is the hand carrying the racket.
>   2.5.6 The free hand is the hand not carrying the racket; the free arm is the arm of the free hand.
>   2.6.1 Service shall start with the ball resting freely on the open palm of the server's stationary free hand.

The rules clearly establish a free hand and a racket hand.

Further

> 9.3 For the same reason he cannot make a good return by throwing his  racket at the ball, because the racket does not “strike” the ball if
>   it  is not held in the racket hand at the moment of impact. However, a
>   player may transfer his racket from one hand to the other during play 
>   and strike the ball with the racket held alternately in either hand, 
>   because the hand holding the racket is automatically the “racket
>   hand”.

Therefore it is assumed that it is illegal to use two racquets as you are allowed to switch between hands.